# USPS rates not showing on front end of magento 1.4.2

Tags: magento, usps

I have a Magento 1.4.2 instillation that was working fine 4/11. Sometime in the last year. I suspect last January 1/12 when the rates changed, I lost my International USPS shipping rates. We do not have a lot of international orders and did not realize this was not working until 9/11 and have not had time to look for a fix until now. I have tried all the patches/fixes I can find with no luck.  I can pull the UPS rates. I have found that API call is being made and that the rates are being returned. It shows up in the log with debug on, but I am getting "shipping method is unavailable" on the front end and when I try to enter an order on the back end.

What am I missing? We only use the USPS for international shipping. But no rates are being returned on the front end when all the USPS rates are selected. How does this just "break"? It was working perfectly when installed in April 4/11. No changes were made to the code or the configuration. I can't figure it out.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I'm also seeing ALL rates returned in the log via XML but my installation still shows `Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.` on the front end...

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick search, it looks like you are not alone. There's a quick fix for this listed here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/271462/

Essentially, the word “Package” was changed to “Parcel”. Copy /app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml to /app/code/local/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml and change:

- ”First-Class Mail Package” to ”First-Class Mail Parcel”
- ”First-Class Mail International Package**” to ”First-Class Mail International Parcel**”

Go to your Admin panel under System > Configuration > Shipping Methods > USPS and select the new methods. Save config.

(Not taking credit for this solution, just trying to help you out!)

Comment: I have tried that. It did not solve my problem. It is returning rates according to the log, but not displaying on the front end.